# element + Variable not working in parentheses

Tags: python, selenium

I have been cracking my head over this seemingly easy code:

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#ember2528 > div > div > p > svg > circle').get_attribute('fill')
```

basically the 2528 is a variable, and I have tried:

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#ember + str(i) > div > div > p > svg > circle').get_attribute('fill')

driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,' + "#ember" + str(i) > div > div > p > svg > circle').get_attribute('fill')

driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#ember & ' + str(i) + ' > div > div > p > svg > circle').get_attribute('fill')
```

Apologies if my format is not in proper order as I am still a novice at this forum, and was trying to figure how to ensure proper code formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a format string to insert the variable value where you want it, like so: `'#ember{} > div > div > p > svg > circle'.format(i)`, which will allow you to insert the value of the variable in place of the `{}` placeholder

Your third attempt also would have worked, except you included the `&` where you shouldn't have. You can simply concatenate the strings like this, `'#ember' + str(i) + ' > div > div > p > svg > circle'`, which would also give you what you want

Comment: Thanks! for the 3rd attempt, thought you would need the & to concatenate. was googling all over, can never seem to learn enough of all these! thanks greatly!!

Comment: @murfyang no problem and yup there are actually several different ways to do this same thing so it can get confusing